# Graph Hierarchical Layout Algorithm

Tags: c#, java, c++, layout, graph

There are many tools and SDKs which layout a graph. ogdf, GraphViz, mxGraph, yEd...

[image]

One of useful layouts is "Hierarchical Layout". But there is no pure algorithm or pseudo code to describe it. Even, There is not a clear definition of this type of layout. Is anyone know about the algorithm?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]
<sub>(source: [yworks.com](http://docs.yworks.com/yfiles/doc/developers-guide/figures/hier-style-explanation-thumb.png))</sub>

Simple hierarchical layout algorithm is visualisation of the ASAP sheduling algorithm (check this lecture [[link]](http://cas.ee.ic.ac.uk/people/gac1/Synthesis/Lecture9.pdf)), so it'd be better to read it, on my view.

BTW your picture is not fully correct - the proposed visualisation is only one of the possible ones.

Imagine, that you have list of node and you know dependence between them.

Node list

```
node4
node2
node5
node1
node3
node6
```

Dependency list

```
node1 -> node2
node2 -> node4
node3 -> node5
node1 -> node3
node3 -> node6
```

- As your first step, you should find nodes with no dependance - this
  would be your layer#1 nodes. Draw them.
- Then find all nodes that depends on layer#1 nodes - this would be your layer#2 nodes.
- And the same thing for the layer#2 and etc.
  Finally, you'll get:

  ```
           node1
          /     \
        node2  node3
         /     /   \
      node4 node5 node6
  ```

This will work only for non-cyclic directed graphs. For the undirected ones you should modify the algorithm a bit (take random node as root), but the main idea, I think, is understandable.

Comment: I check for cycles first with a modified Depth First Search (DFS), e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-in-a-graph/ As BPMN networks are likely to have a few cycles when gateways are involved, you may run a pruning algorithm before the DFS to ignore the flows from a gateway back to a previous activity for the layouting (only).